# Sort on the basis of release version i.e; a.b.c

Tags: mongodb, sorting, version-control, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with field `version` in random order

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae69019"),
                "version" : "1.2.1"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901a"),
                "version" : "1.2.2"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901b"),
                "version" : "1.2.3"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901c"),
                "version" : "1.1.0"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901d"),
                "version" : "1.1.1"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901e"),
                "version" : "1.3.1"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901f"),
                "version" : "1.1.2"
        },
         .
         .
         .
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901f"),
                "version" : "1.9.1"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ea7dfcf33b735ec0ae6901f"),
                "version" : "1.10.1"
        }
]
```

and so on

I want to get an output in sorted order on the basis of the version.

**I am able to sort it after splitting the versions but I don't wanna go through that approach.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the issue with `.find({ }).sort({ version: 1 })`??\

Comment: well does not work when the version increase, eg: when sorting for versions 1.9.4 and 1.10.1 it gives 1.10.1 first and then 1.9.4

Comment: If the sorting is in descending order than yes `1.10.1` will come first.

Comment: nope I'm talking  about `sort({ version: 1 })`

Comment: And in case of descending it gives 1.9.4 first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this behavior with [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/index.html#collation)

First create an index:

```
.createIndex({version:1},{collation:{locale:"en",numericOrdering:true}})
```

And also specify the collation when you need to sort:

```
.find().sort({version:1}).collation({locale:"en",numericOrdering:true})
```

You can get similar behavior without the index, but for non-trivial data sets, it really makes it perform better.